# ¿Existe la sincronia nativa en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Buen dia, estoy trabajando con js, sin embargo de momento cada función que realizo uso async await o retorno una promesa y resuelvo con then, respecto a lo anterior me surgierón algunas dudas respecto a la asincronía del lenguaje.

¿Todas las funciones en JS son asíncronas por naturaleza? ¿hay manera de trabajar JS "síncronamente" haciendo conexiones a BD sin usar await?

si ejecuto una pila de funciones sin ser async o promesas, de tipo:

```
function sumar(){
    let resultado = 0;
    let a = 10,b = 10;
    resultado = a + b;
    console.log(resultado);

}
```

e invoco varias (cientas) funciones (con distintos fines, por ejemplo multiplicaciones, sumas, divisiones, etc) ¿ el motor de JS me lo ejecutará de manera asíncrona nativamente ?

He buscado en la web JS sincrono y solo me aparece información de JS asíncrono. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: [*Javascript es síncrono y de un solo hilo, y tiene varias herramientas que trabajan de forma asíncrona*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035662/5587982) (como Ajax, Fetch, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás confundiendo algunos conceptos. Ten en cuenta que JavaScript, por naturaleza es **síncrono**, lo que quiere decir que, el motor esperará a que una función se termine de ejecutar para continuar con el siguiente proceso.

Para arreglar esto, por el ejemplo que pones, a una conexión de base de datos, **SIEMPRE** se usará una **callback** o **async/await**

---

- **callback**

Un callback es una función que se utiliza de manera asíncrona, normalmente se da como parámetro a una función y es una función anónima. Esta función es llamada por la función principal cuando termina de hacer todos los procesos asíncronos que esta hace, la función callback, normalmente recibe en sus parámetros el resultado de los procesos asíncronos de la función principal.

- **async/await**

Es una manera más práctica de manejar la asincronía, a veces los callbacks pueden resultar algo tediosos y se puede formar la conocida *callback hell*:

[image: Callback hell]

Para evitar esto, se ha implementado el uso de `async`/`await`, `async` es un término para definir que una función va a ser asíncrona y el intérprete debe esperar a que termine su ejecución para seguir con el resto del código, `await` se utiliza cuando vas a llamar a la función. Ten en cuenta que **una función `async` SIEMPRE devolverá una promesa**

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();

// Código proporcionado por MDN
// https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
```

- **promesa**

En JavaScript, una promesa, se usa para manejar la asincronía, usando métodos (`.then`/`.catch`)

Ambos reciben como parámetro una función callback que será la que se ejecutará en cada contexto, o cuando la promesa quiera que se ejecuten

```js
function sumWithPromise(n1, n2) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(n1 + n2);
    // O puedes poner reject() si quieres que se ejecute .catch
  });
}

sumWithPromise(35, 25).then(resultado => {
  console.log(resultado); // 60
}).catch(error => {
  // Algo salió mal
  // En este caso .catch no es necesario porque la promesa nunca llama a este método
});
```

El constructor de una promesa recibe una función *callback*, la cual a su vez recibe dos parámetros: `resolve` y `reject`

Estos parámetros, son los métodos que devuelve la promesa, `resolve` es `then` y `reject` es `catch`. `resolve` se usa para indicar que todos los procesos salieron bien y `reject` se suele ejecutar cuando hubo algún error durante la ejecución de los procesos asíncronos.

---

Ahora que hemos visto los puntos anteriores, podemos responder a tus preguntas sin que quede ninguna duda.

> ¿Todas las funciones en JS son asíncronas por naturaleza?

**No**, las mayoría son síncronas, ahora, hay funciones que incluyen procesos asíncronos y admiten el uso de `async`/`await`, por ejemplo [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> ¿Hay manera de trabajar JS "síncronamente" haciendo conexiones a BD sin usar await?

**Por lo menos en JavaScript, no**; ten en cuenta que las conexiones a bases de datos son netamente **asíncronas**, aunque sea 1ms, el intérprete no esperará ese tiempo para pasar al siguiente proceso sin usar `await`

> ¿El motor de JS me lo ejecutará de manera asíncrona nativamente ?

**Definitiavamente, no**; si no usas `async`, no hay manera de que el intérprete entienda de que debe esperar a que se ejecute una para ejecutar la otra (a menos de que incluyas *callbacks*), el intérprete ejecutará **todo** "de una", de manera síncrona en el orden en  el que has puesto el código.

---

Puedes referenciarte de la documentación de Mozilla en los siguientes enlaces:

- [Función `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, solo quitaría el "no" en _"... el motor no esperará a que una función se termine de ejecutar ..."_

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta. queda claro, gracias y saludos!